# How do I enable my network connection using command prompt?

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, prompt, netsh

How do I enable my network connection using command prompt?

I've tried:

```
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" ENABLE
```

But received this error:

> An interface with this name is not registered with the router.

I know how to disable my network connection using ipconfig/release but when I try ipconfig/renew using command prompt it doesn't seem to be working either.

Answer (score 2):

By using [WMIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Run the following **with elevated/ administrator rights**:

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call disable
```

where 7 is the network interface index number.  You can find it by using:

```
wmic nic get name, index
```

http://itcookbook.net/blog/enabling-and-disabling-nics-commandline-windows

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Shimmy, the fix is to run it with elevated/ admin privileges.  (It hadn't worked for me either, even though it said `Method execution successful.`. It also said `ReturnValue = 5;`.  When running it as admin, that `ReturnValue` changed to `0` and it worked.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to run it with **elevated/ admin privileges**.

(@jfalcon's alternative approach is no different in that respect - it fails when run as non-privileged user and does not even understandably tell you so.  (I edited their answer to reflect this.))